# Flutter Layouts, expand Container in Column to match other widgets width

Tags: flutter, layout

I am creating chat bubbles, I want the width to be defined by the message itself, but then I added a "header" (a Row) with the name of the sender and a decorative line (a Container).
I want this line to fill the available space but when I expand it it pushes the width of the bubble to its maximum regardles of the width of the message. In this sceenshots you can see that the recieved messages are too wide for its content.

This is a simplified version of the code, If I don't put the expanded the red Container is invisible (width 0), with the expanded takes the maximum space available but I want column to remain of the width that determines the message.

Thanks a lot.

```
return Container(
    color: Colors.grey.shade200,
    constraints:
        BoxConstraints(maxWidth: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7)),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text("Juan"),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 3,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Text("Text of the message"),
      ],
    ));
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your try code example?

Comment: you need: `child: IntrinsicWidth(child: Column(...`

Answer (score 0):

pskink nailed it. His answer in the comment:

you need: `child: IntrinsicWidth(child: Column(...` –
pskink

Hopes this also helps somebody else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).